# ANTLR4 doesn't work with custom configuration in Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, antlr, antlr4

I always used succesfully ANTLR4 combined with Maven inside Eclipse.
I just want to change the default directory where I store my grammar, since I do not like the standard path which is *src/main/antlr4*. The issue of this path is the creation of a new java package, that I really do not want.
So I simply decided to create another directory inside my project named *grammar* which contains another directory called *imports*. I did this following simply the website guidelines.
Despite this, when I change the grammar it doesn't generate automatically the new sources, even with the maven commands!

So, this is my configuration file pom.xml:

```
<!-- ANTLR4 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>antlr4</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <libDirectory>grammar/imports</libDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

[image: Eclipse files]

As you can see, the *target* directory is empty. Before this change, there was a *generated-sources* directory inside with all the .java files.

So, where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
<!-- ANTLR4 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>antlr4</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <libDirectory>grammar/imports</libDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The `<configuration>` tag must be at same level than `<goals>` tag, inside `<execution>` tag, according to Maven documentation: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag and https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html

In fact, the documentation in ANTLR4 Maven plugin is wrong:
http://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/latest/examples/libraries.html

Comment: Yes, that was the error. Despite this, now the debug tells me that there are no grammars to compile in my custom path. Am I missing anything more?
Thanks.

Comment: Because `<libDirectory>` is the location of imported grammars and tokens files. The directory where the ANTLR grammar files (*.g4) are located is configured by `<sourceDirectory>`. The default value is ${basedir}/src/main/antlr4, according to [doc](http://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/latest/antlr4-mojo.html).

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @viniciusartur I tried with your answer but it doesn't work. `<configuration>` tag should be at same level with `<artifactId>` tag as I tried. The other info you gave in this answer is awesome, it helps a lot.